# Sum of two int array in aggregation query grouped by another field

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, and having some problems. My document contains fixed size int array that i should sum.

Can mongo sum two int array in a query grouped by another field? In my case, string date.

example data:

```
{d:[1,2], date:"17-01-2020"} {d:[3,4], date:"17-01-2020"} {d:[5,6], date:"18-01-2020"}
```

query result that i want:

```
{d:[4, 6], date:"17-01-2020"} {d:[5,6], date:"18-01-2020"}
```

Comment: Is it exactly and always 2 numbers in the arrays?

Comment: No i gave 2 to be simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixes size of two values then you can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$d" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         d: [
            {$sum:{ $map: { input: "$data", in: { $first: "$$this" } } }},
            {$sum:{ $map: { input: "$data", in: { $last: "$$this" } } }}
         ]
      }
   },
   {$unset: "data"}
])
```

For any length use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$d" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         d: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: { $first: "$data" } }] },
               as: "idx",
               in: { $sum: { $map: { input: "$data", in: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", "$$idx"] } } } }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

The first array determines the length of all the other arrays.

Another approach is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$d", includeArrayIndex: "idx" } },
  { $group: { _id: "$idx", d: { $sum: "$d" } } },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: null, d: { $push: "$d" } } }
])
```

Or if you like to add other fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$d", includeArrayIndex: "idx" } },
  { $group: { _id: "$idx", d: { $sum: "$d" }, date: { $first: "$date" } } },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$date", d: { $push: "$d" } } },
  { $project: { d: 1, date: "$_id" } }
])
```

This works even if the arrays do not all have the same length.

Comment: thank you, is there a solution for the variable size , because i have 1440 length array

Comment: i'm getting error when run on mongo shell : "Unrecognized expression '$first'"

Comment: `$first`/`$last` was introduced in Mongo v4.4. Use `{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 0] }` and ``{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 1] }`` instead

Comment: See also my second solution. I also tried with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) but I failed.

Comment: I was trying to write the query with go. I think second one is easier to write. thanks!

Comment: How do I sum d field group by date if document has date field?

Comment: What do you mean? Please edit your question or open a new one.

Comment: I don't want to only add the date field, I also want to group by date field. Result should like `{{d:[4, 6], date:"17-01-2020"}, {d:[5,6], date:"18-01-2020"}}`

Comment: This works for me :                                                                
 `db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$d", includeArrayIndex: "idx" } },
  { $group: { _id: {idx:"$idx", date: "$date"}, d: { $sum: "$d" } } },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id.date", d: { $push: "$d" } } },
  { $project: { d: 1, date: "$_id" } }
])`